# Errors in a sqrt function program in c++

Tags: c++

**Essentially I was given pseudo code:

"x = 1

repeat 10 times:  x = (x + n / x) / 2

return x"

And the pseudo code for the int main function (int main function to print out my n values in the cout) at the end, in order to create a sqrt function program. I get the following errors on linux2 compiler:

: In function ‘double my_sqrt_1(double)’:

:9:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’

:9:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’

: In function ‘int main()’:
:
15:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘-’ token

:~>  expected primary-expression before ‘return’

Help is much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std; 

double my_sqrt_1(double n) 
{ 
for (int x= 1; x<10; ++x) 
cout<< x << '\t' << x=(x+n/x)/2 << 
return x; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
int n= 3.141459; 
int k= -100,-10,-1,0,1,10,and 100; 
for(auto k : { -100,-10,-1,0,1,10,100}){ 
n=3.14159 * pow (10.0,k); 
cout << "print n,sqrt(n),and my_sqrt_1(n)" ; 
return 0; 
} 
}
```

Comment: You have some fundamental misunderstanding of C++ going on.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use `cout` to do everything. What do you expect `cout << "print n,sqrt(n),and my_sqrt_1(n)"` to do?

Comment: As the saying goes: "This is so bad, it isn't even wrong".

Answer (score 3):

You missed a semicolon at the end of the `cout` line:

```
double my_sqrt_1(double n) 
{ 
  for (int x= 1; x<10; ++x) 
    cout<< x << '\t' << x=(x+n/x)/2;
  return x; 
}
```

The clue is in the error:

> :9:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’

Finding the source of compiler errors can be tricky for those new to C/C++, if you miss a semi-colon the line reported will often differ from the one containing the actual error. As in this case where the `return` line became part of the same statement as the line above.

Also here:

```
int k= -100,-10,-1,0,1,10,and 100;
```

That is not how you define an array, [you should read up on the basics of those](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) since you're new to the game, which is evident here:

```
cout << "print n,sqrt(n),and my_sqrt_1(n)" ;
```

Where you're not calling any functions but instead outputting a static string of text. You need to make the function calls and variable outputs outside of the literal string:

```
cout << "print " << n << "," << sqrt(n) << ", and" << my_sqrt_1(n);
```

Comment: This won't even silence the syntax error, let alone all the other problems. `<<;` is still invalid syntax.

Comment: @chris Thanks! I never knew that! Of course && would still cause a syntax error with the comma and definitely wouldn't do what the OP is asking :)

Comment: Yeah, I never said it was valid in the context :p